# Registering as user fails... Asp.net mvc entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was studiyng this MvcMovie tutorial and I was making some changes.....

Initialy, I had 2 class derived from DbContext, one for movies and other for users...

So I moved them to a single DbContext....

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }


}
```

But now when I try to register myself as user, I get  error in this line of AccountController

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

The error is this one:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'xxx', table 'aspnet-MvcMovie-20120730162622.dbo.UserProfile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I dont understand what is that xxx, I watched in the database and I found no column with that name... I only found xxx in my jquery files, something like this

```
    /* Handles responses to an ajax request:


* - sets all responseXXX fields accordingly
 * - finds the right dataType (mediates between content-type and expected dataType)
 * - returns the corresponding response
 */
```

I dont know what is that.. I didnt study jquery yet.... I dont know if it is part of my problem or it has nothing to do with it...

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with jQuery. If you made changes to your UserProfile model, these changes need to be reflected in your database. Can you post the full Register controller action, and your UserProfile model.